# "Qu'elle a joli d'ailleurs" ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, verbes

I encountered this while reading *Astérix*. Caesar, in leaving Cleopatra's chambers, says:

> Elle est gentille, mais les épices lui montent facilement au nez ... qu'elle a joli d'ailleurs !

The *avoir joli* throws me off most of all, because I would expect it to be *être joli* instead. I would guess the sentence as a whole would translate to:

> She's nice, but the spices get in her nose easily ... she's pretty anyway, though!

I can only assume this is poking fun at the size of her somewhat lengthy nose, although it seems like an odd comment to make. And then there's the *avoir joli*. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: I had to come here because just from the title I recognised where it came from... So I'd say it's not *that* common ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Les épices lui montent facilement au nez

est une adaptation de l'expression française :

> La moutarde me monte au nez.

qui signifie que *je commence à m'énerver*, *à me mettre en colère*.*

Pour l'explication de l'expression « la moutarde me monte au nez » on peut consulter [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/la-moutarde-lui-monte-au-nez.php).

Les auteurs d'Astérix ont remplacé *[moutarde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moutarde_(condiment))* par *[épices](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89pice)* qui est un terme plus générique. Peut-être que pour un public francophone le terme d'épice est plus facilement connoté avec l'orient - associé à l'image de Cléopâtre et de l'Égypte -  que  celui de moutarde.

La mention du nez permet de rebondir sur le nez légendaire de Cléopâtre. Il n'y a pas de subtilité particulière dans la construction de la phrase.

1) les épices lui montent au nez
2) elle a un joli nez

la proposition 2) est transformée en proposition relative dans laquelle le COD *nez* est remplacé par le pronom relatif *que*.
L'autre possibilité pour construire la proposition relative aurait été de dire :

> au nez ... qui est joli d'ailleurs.

Je comprends le choix des auteurs de garder *Cléopâtre* en sujet et *nez* en complément, comme une volonté d'insister sur le lien légendaire qui unit Cléopâtre et son nez.

---

<sup>*I expect the closest equivalent in English would be "My blood is starting to boil".</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a metaphorical and jocular expression, using the noun "nez/nose" for subtle word-play.

The entire sentence means something along the lines of:

> She's usually nice and kind, but just lets trivial things get up her nose {= quick to lose her temper}. Not to imply, of course, that she doesn't have a pretty nose!

---

> 1: les épices **lui montent** facilement **au nez**

Literally: spices can all too easily go up her nose

{Or more like: = get up her nose = little things can irritate her}

---

> 2: qu'elle a (un) joli (**nez**) d'ailleurs !

The noun "nez" is omitted here, which necessitates the use of the verb "avoir".